# Raspberry Pi Remote Desktop with Macbook using SSH

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, python

I have seen so many tutorials on Youtube showing how to connect Raspberry Ri to Macbook using ssh but when i do try it comes up with an error. i have tried this specific [tutorial](https://www.stevencombs.com/raspberrypi/2016/03/24/mirror-raspi-monitor-on-mac.html)  but still comes up with the error shown in the picture below.

I will appreciate it if anyone could help me out as i am still learning to use Raspberry Pi.

[image]

Comment: I confess I haven't read the whole tutorial.  Do you have SSH enabled on the PI?  Click the Raspberry, then Preferences, Raspberry Pi Configuration, then the "Interfaces" tab.  Or, just use the VNC viewer for MacOS.

Comment: What's the result of pinging this host? If they're on the same LAN, try to connect by the hostname (`raspberrypi.local).

Comment: To add to @M.Rostami comment. Open the terminal on your Mac and type: ping -c 4 10.214.199.1 What are the results?

Comment: @M.Rostami these are the results i get when i do ping                                   
PING 10.214.199.1 (10.214.199.1): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2

Comment: @user3880651 Ok, it means that you are not connected to the host/rpi over the network. Make sure the IP address of the raspberry pi and your pc are in the same range. I suggest connecting both of them to a router (DHCP enabled).

Comment: @M.Rostami the issue am having is exactly like this person in this link and i have done the suggestions and still not working https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=169320

Comment: @user3880651 You must solve the `Request timeout` message problem when you are pinging the raspberry pi from the Macbook box. This message means that you are **not connected** (not physically) to the raspberry pi. Therefore, if you are not connected, you can't make a VNC or SSH session/connection to the raspberry pi. Try this one: `ping raspberrypi.local` and add a comment the output here,